# way to join 4 mysql tabels

Tags: mysql, join

Joining 4 tables in MySQL to retrive data.

I need the best way to join 4 tabels:

**1. Users**

```
ID        NAME
1          me
2          you 
3          her
```

**2. Articles**

```
ID   USER_ID   ARTICLE
1       1         etc
2       1         etc
3       2         third
```

**3. Article_comments**

```
ID    ARTICLE_ID    COMMENT    
1        1            etc
2        1            etc
3        3            etc
```

**4. Article points**

```
ID ARTICLE_ID   POINTS
1      1         100  
2      1         200
3      2          50 
4      2          10
```

I need a way to join them to retrieve:

```
ARTICLE | USERNAME | TOTAL COMMENTS PER ARTICLE | TOTAL POINTS PER ARTICLE
```

For example:  For article 1: `etc | me | 2 | 350`
for 2 : `etc | you | 0 | 60` and so one for all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Articles.ID,
    Articles.USER_ID,
    Articles.ARTICLE,
    Users.NAME,
    COUNT(Article_comments.ID) AS `num_comments`,
    SUM(Article_points.POINTS) AS `points`
FROM
    Articles
INNER JOIN
    Users
ON
    Articles.USER_ID = Users.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Article_comments
ON
    Article_comments.ARTICLE_ID = Articles.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Article_points
ON
    Article_points.ARTICLE_ID = Articles.ID
GROUP BY
    Articles.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did as well but is not working properly for records that have more comments and points. For EX the interogation above, article 1 will return :

ID  USER_ID     ARTICLE     NAME    num_comments    points
1     1                etc           me          4            600